# WP Gravity Forms Speed Loading Issue

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I've searched alot about this issue but haven't got any solution, thats why posting here. I've a form In Gravity Forms which has lots of fields and also conditional fields. Say more than 100. Its loading fine but it took over 20 minutes to on website, which really annoying.

So i want something AJAX like solution, mean when page loads, than only first input field will show than on clicking on that further fields should be show via AJAX (or from database). So please help me our on this issue. And thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Page Break" field to break your form into multiple pages.

This way you can have only one or several fields in your first page, then the next set of fields on the next page, etc.

This will not use AJAX by default, but will certainly make your form load faster. And you can implement AJAX loading for the page steps with some custom coding if this is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks Marin foyr your reply, i did this way too but unfortunately its not according to Client's requirement. I can show you my form i you want to look.

Comment: Or any other plugin that does this purpose please let me know